# New Table based on another Table values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to create a new table in Power BI using values of another table. My Original table ARM DATA, has three columns Destination, Sales and Product. I want to create a new table with all the possible DEST and the Sales when the product equal "PHA".

This is my current DAX formula but I don't know how to add only sales for Pharma.

```
New Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'ARM DATA', 
    'ARM DATA'[Destination],
    "Sales", SUM('ARM DATA'[Sales])
)
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this below-

```
New Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER('ARM DATA', 'ARM DATA'[Product] = "PHA"), 
    'ARM DATA'[Destination],
    "Sales", SUM('ARM DATA'[Sales])
)
```

Comment: This works thank you! What if you want to add two conditions, so not only PHA but also Year = 2023. I am using this formula but it is not working 
NewTable = 
SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER('ARM DATA', 'ARM DATA'[Product] = "PHA" && 'ARM DATA'[Calendar Year]=2023),
    'ARM DATA'[Agent Group Name],
    "CWT", SUM('ARM DATA'[Sales])
)

Comment: You can check the data type of column "calendar year". The way you are applying the filter, it should must work if the data type is number.